# How To Post This Question In Perfect Way?

Tags: sentence-construction

Scarlet took Shaun to her home
and he asked this question to her:

> Shaun: So, I take it you've been with a man before.
>   Scarlet: I'm a virgin. I'm just not very good at it.

I want to ask someone else what the Scarlet not very good at.  But people mistaken me and giving answers like:

> Someone is a virgin if they have never had sex before. In this context, "I'm not very good at it" means she is not experienced with having sexual intercourse.

That is not my question. Instead I want to know how to phrase the question in proper way?

Example:

Scene: Amazon warrior asked a question to Hippolyte after Diana left to Human world with Steve Trevor on boat.

> Warrior: Should you have told to Diana?
>   Hippolyte: The more she knows, the sooner he'll find her.

If I want to ask someone else what the Warrior meant, then my question is:

> What is it that Hippolyte told Diana that that the Warrior is now questioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask something like:

> What does Scarlet mean when she says, "I'm not very good at [being a virgin]?

This focuses the question on the meaning of the quoted phrase.  You could also make it an indirect paraphrase of the quote with something like:

> What does Scarlet mean when she says she's not very good at being a virgin?

In a similar way you could ask:

> What does the Warrior mean when she asks Hippolyte, "Should you have told her?"

Or paraphrase:

> What does the Warrior think Hippolyte should have told Diana?

These are only a few of the many ways you could ask this kind of question.

Side note: Scarlet's quote is meant to be *funny*, because virginity is not something that requires *skill*.  You either are or you are not a virgin. You are not supposed to take what she says to be *literally* true.  The entire movie (*Hot Shots*) is full of these kind of [farcical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farcical) elements, that you are meant to laugh at because they don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows poor construction: "I want to ask someone else what the Scarlet not very good at." which introduces some confusion into interpreting the dialog. Scarlet: "I'm not very good at it" means she is not experienced with having sexual intercourse... That is not my question.

So why don't you have Shaun reply to Scarlet..."So Scarlet, why have you invited me to your home? What else are you not good at?"

If that does not help, perhaps you should clarify this: "I want to ask someone else" by telling us what is going on here? Who is this someone else, and why do you want to ask that other person about Scarlet's experience of copulation? This jumps out of the example scenario.

Comment: Sorry, you just didn't understand question.